# padding for Bootstrap column only for large grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to add padding for example for large grid only and for medium grid no padding ?

Large grid with padding:

```html
    <div class="col-lg-4 pl-3">
    </div>
```

Medium grid without padding:

```html
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
```

how to combine them together and use padding for large grid only ?

Comment: You can add `lg` to the `pl`, so you can do: `<div class="col-lg-4 pl-lg-3">`

Comment: Are you using both Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5? If not, please remove the tag for the version you are not using.

Answer (score 1):

For adding padding for any particular type of grid you use these classes-

Padding Left: `pl-*-#`

Here, in `*` use the grid sizes like `lg`, `md`, `sm` ...
and in `#` use the values `1`, `2`, `3`, ...

Like this way, you may use `pb` for `padding-bottom`, `pr` for `padding-right`, `pt` for `padding-top`, `px` for `padding-horizontal` and `py` for `padding-vertical`

You may find details here in `Utility Spacing` section https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/